# excel vba macro reading text files, one line in separate cell

Tags: excel, vba, text-files, delimiter, readfile

Text file looks like below

a,   John,   "2014-2", ...

d,   Will,   "2016-7" , ...

I want to put **element a in row 1, col 1**, **John in row 1 col 2**, **d in cell row 2, col 1**, etc. Please help. Thanks. below are the code I have

```
Sub Importdata()
Open "C:\Users\apple\desktop\12345.txt" For Input As #1
r = 0
  Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, Data
    ActiveCell.Offset(r, 0) = Data
    r = r + 1
  Loop
Close #1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You can split each line using `Split` and `,` as delimiter

Try  this it works fine:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Importdata()

Dim cet
Dim r As Long
Dim Data
Dim wk AS worksheet

Set wk = sheet1

Open "C:\Users\apple\desktop\12345.txt" For Input As #1
r = 1

  Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, Data
    cet = Split(Data, ",")

    if len(join(cet)) > 0 then        
     wk.Cells(r, 1) = cet(0)
     wk.Cells(r, 2) = cet(1)
    ENd if

     r = r + 1
  Loop
Close #1
End Sub
```

Comment: Try it with source string like `a, John, "2014-2", "Orange, Strawberry", ...`

Comment: I know it will fail in that case but OP just wanted first two elements

Comment: OK, now I see. Then it's a good idea to use `cet = Split(Data, ",", 3)

Comment: I have tested the result, messagebox would first prints out first two elements, then it gets "run time error 9-subscript out of range"@newguy

Comment: @Michael Because in your text file there maybe some lines with less than 2 commas that's why. Try updated code .

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `QueryTables` property, importing and parsing the lines in one step.  Easiest method is to do this using the Macro Recorder (Using the `Data ► Get External Data ► From Text` option from the Excel menu), then tweak to suit. In Excel, that would bring up the Text Import wizard, but you can also do it in VBA. Below is an example where I browse for the file, but you can easily hard-code it as you have in your original macro.  Also note that I have explicitly declared the workbook and worksheets; you can easily change this if you wish.

**EDIT** Minor tweaks added for clarification

```
Option Explicit
Sub ImportData()
    Dim sMyFile As Variant
    Dim WS As Worksheet, WB As Workbook

Set WB = ThisWorkbook
Set WS = WB.Worksheets("sheet1")

sMyFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files(*.txt), *.txt")
If sMyFile <> False Then

    With WS.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" & sMyFile, _
        Destination:=WS.Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "TestText"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = xlWindows
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you  so much Ron. Appreciate your help

Comment: @Michael  Glad to help.  I suggest you also examine help for each of the properties listed in the `Add` so as to ascertain how you might want to tweak them. Some are obvious.  For the others, you can access this by placing the cursor in a property, then hitting `F1`

Comment: @Michael I made some minor tweaks as the original QueryTable had the file name hard coded.  If it works for you, please mark my response as the answer.  If not, let me know so we can tweak as needed.